# Connecting rotational period with period of oscillation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

Recently I have been thinking about if rotational period is somehow related to period of oscillation for SHMs. My original question was how velocity of something impacting a spring affects its amplitude, and I was able to find the following by using energy conservation for springs:

$\dfrac{1}{2}mx^2  = \dfrac{1}{2}mw^2A^2$

$v^2 = w^2A^2$

$w = \dfrac{v}{A}$

$\dfrac{2π}{T} = \dfrac{v}{A}$

$T = \dfrac{2πA}{v}$

At first I was sceptical of my result as I had never seen it anywhere else. Then I realized it looked very similar to the period of orbital rotation, which I did not expect. I thought about it and realized SHMs look very much like looking at a rotational movement on the side. So this result does not seem to be incorrect and it seems like the rotational period equation can also be applied to SHMs, though I am not sure.

I then tried to connect my result to the period formula for SHMs, which resulted in

$\dfrac{2πA}{v}$ = $2π\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{k}}$

$A = v\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{k}}$

$v = A\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$

So this seems like a way to find amplitude and velocity based off of mass and the spring constant. Are these results correct? I'm not very sure if I did anything wrong or not. If they aren't wrong, why doesn't this appear in textbooks or elsewhere?

(Btw my knowledge of physics is limited to AP Physics 1 and my knowledge of calculus is limited at best.)

Comment: You are right. They are closely connected. [Comparing Simple Harmonic Motion(SHM) to Circular Motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSBw-JyFgZk)